# Parse User name for extracting user location Twitter

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am trying to scrape user location with respect to user names from twitter.

Input: The user list has more than 50K User names

```
AkkiPritam,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#chennaifloods
AkkiPritam,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#bhoomikatrust
AkkiPritam,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#akshaykumar
gischethans,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#chennaifloods
mid_day,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#bollywood
mid_day,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#chennaifloods
Nanthivarman16,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#admkfails
Nanthivarman16,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#jayafails
Nanthivarman16,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#stickergovt
Nanthivarman16,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#chennaifloods
AdilaMatra,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#chennaifloods
AdilaMatra,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#climatechange
AdilaMatra,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#delhichokes
AdilaMatra,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#smog
HDFCERGOGIC,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#chennaifloods
HDFCERGOGIC,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#tnfloods
ImSoorej,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#chennaifloods
ImSoorej,6.77E+17,12/15/2015,#chennaimicr
```

Code: I want to find geo location possibly geo coordinates.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pandas as pd
import csv

consumer_key = 'xyz'
consumer_secret = 'xyz'
access_token = 'xyz'
access_token_secret = 'xyz'

data = pd.read_csv('user_keyword.csv')
df = ['user_name', 'user_id', 'date', 'keyword']

def get_user_details(username):
        userobj = api.get_user(username)
        return userobj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #authenticating the app (https://apps.twitter.com/)
    auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    username = df['user_name']
    userOBJ = get_user_details(username)
    print(userOBJ.location)
```

Error: Trouble parsing the usernames into program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user_profile_location.py", line 38, in <module>
    username = df['user_name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: umm. `df` is not a dictionary, it's a list of strings -- you need to access `df` elements using integer indices.

Comment: @ChitharanjanDas Thanks ! What changes do I make ??

Comment: your code here `data = pd.read_csv('user_keyword.csv')` creates the DataFrame.  `df = ['user_name', 'user_id', 'date', 'keyword']` creates a Python list and assigns the list to the variable `df`. If your csv has headings that match the items in the list then you need to use `data['user_name']` My best suggestion would be to read the pandas [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)

Comment: @toasteez csv does not have heading I m assigning it

Comment: Then the answer below has the solution for assigning it

Comment: @toasteez and that is giving the authentication error.. Where as i am using the same keys for scraping data with keyword search.

Comment: Check the terms of use of the API `api.get_user(username)` It may be that this API is only valid for a single user.  I've not played with Twitter Api's but it looks interesting.  Also look a this [link](http://register.automatingosint.com/clkn/http/automatingosint.com/blog)

Comment: @toasteez yeah I doubt that too.. Only single user then it might not solve the purpose. I am doing my best to search more about this..  Thanks for the suggestions..  But thr has to be something that can be done to achieve..  I also looked into twython instead if tweepy

Comment: Try with your user if it returns the locations then your code is correct and you have to dig more into the api's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 'data' to define your DataFrame and 'df' for what I think should be the columns of the DataFrame

```
data = pd.read_csv('user_keyword.csv')
df = ['user_name', 'user_id', 'date', 'keyword']
```

I assume that the user_keyword.csv file has no header, try adding:

```
data.columns = df
```

It will change the column names to the values stored in df.
Then later instead of:

```
username = df['user_name']
```

Try:

```
username = data['user_name']
```

Keep in mind that now username is a whole column so `get_user_details(username)` should not be expecting a single string.

Comment: I am getting this error :  `
  File "user_profile_location.py", line 40, in <module>
    userOBJ = get_user_details(username)
  File "user_profile_location.py", line 29, in get_user_details
    userobj = api.get_user(username)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Could not authenticate you.', u'code': 32}]`

Comment: `userOBJ = get_user_details(username)`  try substituting the username with your username.  If this works then its because you are trying to authenticate a user of which you do not have the credentials.