# While downloading tweets filter the keywords in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I am trying to download tweets with locations. I can very well download them, But I also want to filter the `#keywords` and if possible `@Mentions` in to a separate column along with other columns.

Code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import sys
import time

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

ckey = 'abc'
csecret = 'abc'
atoken = 'abc'
asecret = 'abc'

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret, 'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    print " Scraping data now" # Enter lat and long and radius in Kms  q='hello'
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,geocode="40.712784,-74.005941,1000km",since='2016-07-10',until='2016-07-11',lang='en',count=100)
    results=[]
    for item in cursor.items(10000): # Remove the limit to 1000

        results.append(item)

def toDataFrame(tweets):
    # COnvert to data frame
    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()

    DataSet['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetText'] = [tweet.text.encode('utf-8') for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetRetweetCt'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetFavoriteCt'] = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetSource'] = [tweet.source for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetCreated'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userID'] = [tweet.user.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userScreen'] = [tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userName'] = [tweet.user.name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userCreateDt'] = [tweet.user.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userDesc'] = [tweet.user.description for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFollowerCt'] = [tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFriendsCt'] = [tweet.user.friends_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userLocation'] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userTimezone'] = [tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Coordinates'] = [tweet.coordinates for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['GeoEnabled'] = [tweet.user.geo_enabled for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Language'] = [tweet.user.lang for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_place= []
    #users_retweeted = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.place:
            tweets_place.append(tweet.place.full_name)
        else:
            tweets_place.append('null')
    DataSet['TweetPlace'] = [i for i in tweets_place]
    #DataSet['UserWhoRetweeted'] = [i for i in users_retweeted]
    
    return DataSet
        
DataSet = toDataFrame(results)
DataSet.to_csv('NewYork_10_07.csv',index=False)
print "Download Completed"
```

The code above works fine for scraping tweets with Lat-long But how do I include the statements to filter the keywords and mentions from `tweetText` into two separate columns ?

Comment: You would probably want to pass the field `DataSet['tweetText']` to a function that uses [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) to grab them and create new fields appended to the `DataFrame`

Comment: @toasteez Yes, But how and where do I include in this program. I already have done that as another program.

Comment: you need to create the function then after you have your dataframe of tweets pass that dataframe to the function to return the new dataframe with the extra columns.  Probably after the `DataSet = toDataFrame(results)`

Comment: @toasteez Thanks ! I'll try ... can you please help me with a suggestion for this one too .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524071/parse-user-name-for-extracting-user-location-twitter