# Pandas gives an error from str.extractall('#')

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter all the `#` keywords from the tweet text. I am using `str.extractall()` to extract all the keywords with `#` keywords. 
This  is the first time I am working on filtering keywords from the tweetText using pandas. Inputs, code, expected output and error are given below.

Input:

```
userID,tweetText 
01, home #sweet home
01, #happy #life 
02, #world peace
03, #all are one
04, world tour
```

and so on... the total datafile is in GB size scraped tweets with several other columns. But I am interested in only two columns.

Code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Text.csv', index_col=0, header=None, names=['userID', 'tweetText'])

fout = data['tweetText'].str.extractall('#')

print fout
```

Expected Output:

```
userID,tweetText 
01,#sweet
01,#happy 
01,#life 
02,#world
03,#all
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keyword_split.py", line 7, in <module>
    fout = data['tweetText'].str.extractall('#')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 1621, in extractall
    return str_extractall(self._orig, pat, flags=flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 694, in str_extractall
    raise ValueError("pattern contains no capture groups")
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

Thanks in advance for the help. What should be the simplest way to filter keywords with respect to userid?

Output Update:

When used only this the output is like above 
`s.name = "tweetText"
data_1 = data[~data['tweetText'].isnull()]`

The output in this case has empty `[]` and the userID at still listed and for those which has keywords has an array of keywords and not in list form.

When used only this the output us what needed but with `NAN`

```
s.name = "tweetText"
data_2 = data_1.drop('tweetText', axis=1).join(s)
```

The output here is correct format but those with no keywords has yet considered and has NAN

If it is possible we got to neglect such userIDs and not shown in output at all.In next stages I am trying to calculate the frequency of keywords in which the `NAN` or empty `[]` will also be counted and that frequency may compromise the far future classification.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not too tied to using `extractall`, you can try the following to get your final output:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import re


data_text = """userID,tweetText
01, home #sweet home
01, #happy #life 
02, #world peace
03, #all are one
"""

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_text),header=0)

data['tweetText'] = data.tweetText.apply(lambda x: re.findall('#(?=\w+)\w+',x))
s = data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['tweetText']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
s.name = "tweetText"
data = data.drop('tweetText', axis=1).join(s)

     userID tweetText
0       1    #sweet
1       1    #happy
1       1     #life
2       2    #world
3       3      #all
4       4       NaN
```

You drop the rows where the textTweet column returns `Nan`'s by doing the following:

```
data = data[~data['tweetText'].isnull()]
```

This should return:

```
   userID tweetText
0       1    #sweet
1       1    #happy
1       1     #life
2       2    #world
3       3      #all
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works wonders !! thank you so much ... Except for the `Nan` for the `userID` with no keywords. This what I have been trying for.

Comment: You're welcome! If the `Nan`'s aren't presentable enough, you can use `fillna` to fill the `Nan`'s with something of your choosing.

Comment: It is not about presentable those with no `#keywords` need not be included but is will it possible to put some other keyword within the tweetText ?

Comment: The ones with no #keywords should be included. They just don't have any data in them. That's why you have the `Nan`. If you don't mind, can you show me more data so I know where this is happening?

Comment: I did include a new line in input in the question. I cannot put real tweets with userid so this is a replica. The tweets some times do not have `#` tags it has just a plain message.

Comment: What do you want to return if the tweet does not contains a `#` character?

Comment: Any suggestions ? These tweets are scraped with respect to location so I cannot be specific about important words.

Comment: Why can't just return the whole tweet if it does not contain a `#` character? It's difficult for me to make good suggestions because I don't know what kind of analysis you are looking to do with the data.

Comment: As of now I want to work only with #keywords eventually will find the frequency of these keywords with respect to userids and later classify them. The idea for non # keyword to put in list is only to not loose the data. As NAN results would not be considered while classification.

Comment: Maybe you can replace the `Nan`'s with `#tobeignored`, so that when you do a classification, you will use `#tobeignored` as the group that does not use hashtags?

Comment: or may be neglect those userids completely while writing the output ?

Comment: I just edited the answer to include some code for removing rows where the `tweetText` column contains `Nan`'s.

Comment: May I request a little help with this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524071/parse-user-name-for-extracting-user-location-twitter

Comment: When used the new update statement I am getting different format of answer. `714252803389190146                                                 []
714252629879169024   [#Fan, #AdityaNarayan, #SajidWajid, #SaReGaMaPa]
714250755742388225  [#Novomoskovsk, #Engineering, #Veterans, #Job,...`The empty userID has a empty `[]` and others are shown as array with braces but not as list.

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you're saying

Comment: And what seems to be the problem with that output?

Comment: Updated Again. Those userids which do not have any #Keywords they are not needed in output of any kind.

Comment: They should not be in the output. We removed them with `data = data[~data['tweetText'].isnull()]`

Comment: Can you please check the rar with real input and output including the program https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tmcmc7hbi53qmb/stack_prog.rar?dl=0

Comment: The problem with your script is that you are removing the `Nan`'s too early. You want to remove the `Nan`'s after you have already done the `join` operation.

Answer (score 8):

Set braces in your calculus :

```
fout = data['tweetText'].str.extractall('(#)')
```

instead of

```
fout = data['tweetText'].str.extractall('#')
```

Hope that will work

Comment: This is in fact the way the extract method expects the regex pattern, and should be the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem getting "ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups".

Answer (score 3):

The `extractall` function requires a regex pattern **with capturing groups** as the first argument, for which you have provided `#`.

A possible argument could be `(#\S+)`. The braces indicate a capture group, in other words what the `extractall` function needs to extract from each string.

Example:

```
data="""01, home #sweet home
01, #happy #life 
02, #world peace
03, #all are one
"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), 
                 header=None, 
                 names=['col1', 'col2'],
                 index_col=0)

df['col2'].str.extractall('(#\S+)')
```

The error `ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups` doesn't appear anymore with the above code (meaning the issue in the question is solved), but this hits a bug in the current version of pandas (I'm using `'0.18.1'`).

The error returned is:

```
AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 6 columns
```

The issue is described [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13382).

If you would try `df['col2'].str.extractall('#(\S)')`(which will give you the first letter of every hashtag, you'll see that the `extractall` function works as long as the captured group only contains a single character (which matches the issue description). As the issue is closed, it should be fixed in an upcoming pandas release.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestuon. The error is same even after changing. May be any alternative to extractall?

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Helps a lot :) I have same version of pandas as well.

Comment: @Merlin http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/kspeeckaert/012822e05c043db103617f2c738ade88

Comment: May I request a little help with this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524071/parse-user-name-for-extracting-user-location-twitter

Comment: In the meanwhile you can try using two parenthesis and dropping the extra column:
    df['col2'].str.extractall('((#\S+))')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Since it filters for '#', your NAN should not exist.

```
    data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_text),header=0, index_col=0 )
    data = data["tweetText"].str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().reset_index().rename(columns = {0:"tweetText"}).drop('level_1', 1)
    data = data[data['tweetText'].str[0] == "#"].reset_index(drop=True) 


     userID tweetText
0       1    #sweet
1       1    #happy
2       1     #life
3       2    #world
4       3      #all
```

@Abdou method:

```
def try1():
     data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_text),header=0)
     data['tweetText'] = data.tweetText.apply(lambda x: re.findall('#(?=\w+)\w+',x))
     s = data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['tweetText']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
     s.name = "tweetText"
     data = data.drop('tweetText', axis=1).join(s)
     data = data[~data['tweetText'].isnull()]

%timeit try1()
 100 loops, best of 3: 7.71 ms per loop
```

@Merlin method

```
def try2():
    data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_text),header=0, index_col=0 )
    data = data["tweetText"].str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().reset_index().rename(columns = {'level_0':'userID',0:"tweetText"}).drop('level_1', 1)
    data = data[data['tweetText'].str[0] == "#"].reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit try2()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.36 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the short solution. But, in the output if you see the first entry in userID is shown `0` where as it is supposed to be `1` .

Comment: May I request a little help with this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524071/parse-user-name-for-extracting-user-location-twitter